# MYSQL Database and fetchmethod not syncing up?

Tags: javascript, frontend, fetch-api

So basically my website has this combat feature. It allows 2 players to choose their characters yada yada.

The problem is that first turn, it displays player 1's moves correctly, once they select their move, it refreshes the page and it should be second turn now but it still displays player 1's moves. If i select another move, it becomes turn 3, showing player 2's moves.

when i check the mysql, it shows the correct moves, but whatever i fetchmethod, it is always 1 turn behind.

some code below( i tried merging them as i thought the combatturnoutcome was not updating fast enough so i made it go first before seeing the player's moves)

```
`    // url = new URL(document.URL);
// const urlParams = url.searchParams;
// const last_combat_id = urlParams.get(("combat_id"));
// console.log("Document URL:", document.URL);
// console.log("Combat ID from URL Params:", urlParams.get("combat_id"));

last_combat_id = localStorage.getItem("lastCombatId")

const processCombatCallback = (responseStatusOutcome, responseDataOutcome) => {
  console.log("responseStatus:", responseStatusOutcome);
  console.log("responseData:", responseDataOutcome);

  const outcomeList = document.getElementById("outcomeList");

    const displayItem = document.createElement("div");
    displayItem.className = "col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 p-3";

    displayItem.innerHTML = `
      <div class="card-label">
        <!-- Image at the top -->
        <img src="path/to/your/image.jpg" alt="Move Image" class="card-image">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">${responseDataOutcome.message}</h5> 
          <p class="card-text">
            Player 1 Hp: ${responseDataOutcome.Stats.Player1.HP} <br>
            Player 1 Mana: ${responseDataOutcome.Stats.Player1.Mana} <br>
            Player 2 HP: ${responseDataOutcome.Stats.Player2.HP} <br>
            Player 2 Mana: ${responseDataOutcome.Stats.Player2.Mana} <br>
            Turn Number: ${responseDataOutcome.TurnNumber} <br>
        
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-primary selectMoveBtn" data-move-id="${responseDataOutcome.move_id}">Select Move</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;

    outcomeList.appendChild(displayItem);

  // Make one request for the entire set of outcomes

}


const data = {
  player1_id: localStorage.getItem("player1_id"),
  player2_id: localStorage.getItem("player2_id"),
  last_combat_id: last_combat_id,
  move_id: localStorage.getItem("selectedMoveId"),
};

console.log("the data before process playerturn",data)

fetchMethod(currentUrl + "/api/combat/processPlayerTurn", processCombatCallback, "PUT", data, localStorage.getItem("token"));

const displayPlayerMovesCallback = (responseStatus, responseData) => {
  console.log("responseStatus:", responseStatus);
  console.log("responseData:", responseData);

  const moveList = document.getElementById("moveList");
  responseData.forEach((move) => {
    const displayItem = document.createElement("div");
    displayItem.className = "col-xl-3 col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 p-3";

    // Determine the image source based on character type
    let imageSrc = `./assets/${move.move_name}.png`;

    console.log(move.move_name);

    displayItem.innerHTML = `
      <div class="card-label">
        <!-- Image at the top -->
        <img src=${imageSrc} alt="Move Image" class="card-image">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">${move.move_name}</h5> 
          <p class="card-text">
            Power: ${move.power} <br>
            Mana Cost: ${move.mana_cost} <br>
          </p>
        </div>
        <div class="card-footer">
          <button class="btn btn-primary selectMoveBtn" data-move-id="${move.move_id}">Select Move</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    `;

    moveList.appendChild(displayItem);

    // Set up the event listener for the current button
    const selectMoveBtn = displayItem.querySelector(".selectMoveBtn");
    selectMoveBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
      // Handle the selection of the move
      const selectedMoveId = selectMoveBtn.getAttribute("data-move-id");
      console.log("Selected Move ID:", selectedMoveId);
      localStorage.setItem("selectedMoveId", selectedMoveId);

      window.location.href = `combat.html?combat_id=${last_combat_id}`;
    });
  });
};



const moveData = {
  player1_id: localStorage.getItem("player1_id"),
  player2_id: localStorage.getItem("player2_id"),
};
console.log("Move Data:", moveData);

// fetchMethod(currentUrl + `/api/combat/playerMoves?player1_id=${moveData.player1_id}&player2_id=${moveData.player2_id}`, displayPlayerMovesCallback, "GET", null, null);
fetchMethod(currentUrl + `/api/combat/playerMoves/${localStorage.getItem("player1_id")}/$       {localStorage.getItem("player2_id")}`, displayPlayerMovesCallback, "GET");     `

`
```